# SSRS 2014 Report parts and Subreports redirects to http: instead of https:

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs, ssrs-2014

I am looking to find a solution for the SSRS 2014 server redirects to http url instead of https for all the subreports and other report parts like subscription , security , datasources etc .

What I have done so far

1. On the rsreportserver config file changed the value for  from 0 to 3 , SSRS does not work when this value is set to anything other than 0 .
2. Added the url to rsreportserver config file  to contain the https:// version of my report server
3. Added a registry entry to have DisableLoopbackCheck with value 1 and restarted the server
   (Tried this solution already [SSRS : Bug using SSL (https://)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163016/ssrs-bug-using-ssl-https))
4. Our SSRS does not have an IIS , its managed in the Reporting services configuration manager where we have bound the ssl certificates with https: url port 443
   I have also tried removing http: with port 80 on the Web Service manage and Report server url .

This problem is taking a lot of time and is affecting a lot of production user when they get redirected to sub reports they will have to manually key in https: on the address every time when the report is run .

Let me know if you require any detail and help me fix the problem .

Thanks in Advance